# pass to javascript class object is serialized in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, json

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var seferim = jss.Serialize(sefer);
                string asds = seferim.ToString();
                asds = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(asds);

function otobusGetir(id, b, i) {
        id = encodeURI(id);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'BiletSatis.aspx/Getir',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '{"id":"' + id + '","Binis":"' + b + '","Inis":"' + i + '"}',
            success: function () { },
            error: function () {  }
        })
```

[WebMethod]
        public static string Getir(string id, string Binis, string Inis)
        {
            string a = id;
            string b = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(id);
            return null;
        }

The problem is javascript function cannot take parameter(Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL) which is serialized.How i can totally done tihs job?

The problem is that this is not working while javascript function run it can not take argument,how can totaly don this job

Comment: Can you add the javascript code aswell. The json you posted is valid. You should be able to deserialize in javascript.

Comment: I don't under stand what you are trying to do. your json literal looks correct. seferim shall be able to pass to any js function as parameter with no problem. Can you show your code that is broken?

Comment: "how can i send a data like above is a class to javascript" can you rephrase this? I think it's the subject of the question, but I'm not sure.

Comment: the problem caused while function getting argument,function can not get it and says that Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
function otobusGetir(id, b, i) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'BiletSatis.aspx/Getir',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: id, Binis: b, Inis: i }),
        success: function () { },
        error: function () {  }
    });
}
```

and to call the function:

```
otobusGetir(123, 'foo bar', 'baz');
```

and the page method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Getir(string id, string Binis, string Inis)
{
    // don't use any Html decoding here. The parameters will
    // already be properly formatted so you can use them directly

    return null;
}
```

Comment: the problem caused while function getting argument,function can not get it and says that Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Right, you seem to be trying to call an ASPX page method. I have updated my answer.

Comment: your thing can not be work because javascript can not take parameter this method can accept parameter but in aspx page method decode before decode and after decode are some how can i fixed it

Comment: I think the language barrier is too big for me understanding what you are talking about.